# Python 3 list comparison of sub element

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with the following elements

```
queue = [[(1, 5), 4, (1, 4)], [(2, 2), 6, (2, 3)], 
         [(1, 3), 6, (2, 3)], [(1, 3), 6, (1, 4)]]
```

and another one called

```
neighbors = [[(1, 5), 4, (1, 4)], [(1, 3), 6, (1, 4)], 
             [(2, 4), 4, (1, 4)], [(0, 4), 6, (1, 4)]]
```

How can I check that the first tuple element on the second list exists in the first?

Usually I would do something like:

```
for item in neighbors:
    if item[0] in queue:
        Do something...
```

But this is missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Build an index into `queue` like:

```
queue_exists = set(q[0] for q in queue)
```

Then test if in `queue` like:

```
if item[0] in queue_exists:
```

#### Test Code:

```
queue = [[(1, 5), 4, (1, 4)], [(2, 2), 6, (2, 3)], [(1, 3), 6, (2, 3)],
         [(1, 3), 6, (1, 4)]]

neighbors = [[(1, 5), 4, (1, 4)], [(1, 3), 6, (1, 4)], [(2, 4), 4, (1, 4)],
             [(0, 4), 6, (1, 4)]]

queue_exists = set(q[0] for q in queue)

for item in neighbors:
    if item[0] in queue_exists:
        print(item)
```

#### Results:

```
[(1, 5), 4, (1, 4)]
[(1, 3), 6, (1, 4)]
```